# Saving a 10x1 line figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a series of figures that I'm creating, 2 of which are line plots. I'm trying to save these 2 line plots as jpegs but I'm having some trouble. Using saveas doesn't work.

I also tried to use print and hgsave to do this, but to no avail. I think hgsave can only save to the format fig, so that would explain that one. I can save the figure manually using file > save as, but I would like to able to do this in the code as well.

This code can replicate the problem:

```
x = categorical({'X1', 'X2'});
test = randi(5, 2, 10);
figure;
Test_Line = plot(x, test, 'marker', 'o', 'linestyle', '-');
saveas(Test_Line, 'testline.jpg')
```

Ideally, the code should be able to save the figure to a jpeg file. Though if that isn't possible then any of the image file extensions should suffice. Instead, I get this error:

Conversion to matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line from cell is not possible.

Is this something to do with the fact that it is a 10x1 line object?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the figure handle, not the handle to the line objects. You can either refer to the current figure using [`gcf`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html):

```
x = categorical({'X1', 'X2'});
test = randi(5, 2, 10);
figure;
Test_Line = plot(x, test, 'marker', 'o', 'linestyle', '-');
saveas(gcf, 'testline.jpg')
```

Or (e.g. when you have multiple figures created, and want to save them at the end of your script), store the figure handle:

```
x = categorical({'X1', 'X2'});
test = randi(5, 2, 10);
fig = figure;
Test_Line = plot(x, test, 'marker', 'o', 'linestyle', '-');
saveas(fig, 'testline.jpg')
```